# how to float divs when using search filter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a gallery that gets filtered two ways. One by click of a button and the other with a search filter. Filters are working perfectly, except when divs are hidden on filter the remaining showing divs do not float next to each other.

**this is what it looks like before filtered:**
[image]

**After filtering this is what it looks like:**

[image]

How can I get it all of dancer2 to be next to each other and only start a new row every 4 dancers?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".column").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.column {
  float: right;
  display: none;
  /* Hide columns by default */
}

.content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row container" style="margin: auto;">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names..">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-8" style="text-align: right;">
    <div id="myBtnContainer" class="container" style="padding-bottom: 2rem;">
      <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('teachera')"> teachera</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('teacherb')"> teacherb</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('teacherc')"> teacherc</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!--DANCER GALLERY-->
<div class="row container" style="margin: auto; margin-bottom: 2rem;">
  <div class="col-sm-3 column teachera">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/175x250" alt="Dancer1" style="width:80%; height: 200px;">
        <h4>Dancer1</h4>
        <p>teachera</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>


  <div class="col-sm-3 column teachera">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/175x250" alt="Dancer2" style="width:80%; height: 200px;">
        <h4>Dancer2</h4>
        <p>teachera</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3 column teachera">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/175x250" alt="Dancer3" style="width:80%; height: 200px;">
        <h4>Dancer3</h4>
        <p>teachera</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3 column teachera">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/175x250" alt="Dancer4" style="width:80%; height: 200px;">
        <h4>Dancer4</h4>
        <p>teachera</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row container" style="margin: auto; margin-bottom: 2rem;">
  <div class="col-sm-3 column teacherb">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/175x250/ff0000" alt="Dancer1a" style="width:80%; height: 200px;">
        <h4>Dancer1</h4>
        <p>teacherb</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3 column teacherb">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/175x250/ff0000" alt="Dancer2a" style="width:80%; height: 200px;">
        <h4>Dancer2</h4>
        <p>teacherb</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3 column teacherb">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/175x250/ff0000" alt="Dancer3a" style="width:80%; height: 200px;">
        <h4>Dancer3</h4>
        <p>teacherb</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3 column teacherb">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/175x250/ff0000" alt="Dancer4a" style="width:80%; height: 200px;">
        <h4>Dancer4</h4>
        <p>teacherb</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row container" style="margin: auto; margin-bottom: 2rem;">
  <div class="col-sm-3 column teacherc">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/175x250/ffff00" alt="Dancer1b" style="width:80%; height: 200px;">
        <h4>Dancer1</h4>
        <p>teacherc</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3 column teacherc">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/175x250/ffff00" alt="Dancer2b" style="width:80%; height: 200px;">
        <h4>Dancer2</h4>
        <p>teacherc</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3 column teacherc">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/175x250/ffff00" alt="Dancer3b" style="width:80%; height: 200px;">
        <h4>Dancer3</h4>
        <p>teacherc</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3 column teacherc">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/175x250/ffff00" alt="Dancer4b" style="width:80%; height: 200px;">
        <h4 class="dancerName">Dancer4</h4>
        <p>teacherc</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: row inside the container and not in the same element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a new div with the "row" class it will start a new row. If you want all of those elements to show side-by-side, they should all be in the same "row" div. The bootstrap styles will automatically keep a maximum of 4 pictures side-by-side and wrap to a new row (because you have col-sm-3 as the class for the individual pictures). Bootstrap rows go up to 12 units long. Each time a new element is added, if it exceeds the 12, it will wrap to the next line.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!